# Fallo al exportar proyecto a Heroku

Tags: laravel-5, heroku

Veran, quiero trasladar un proyecto de Laravel a Heroku.
Para ello, he creado en Heroku un nuevo proyecto llamado "ficherodejuegos":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo siguiente es pasarle el proyecto que voy a utilizar, al que llamo "periodico".
Para ello activo el cmd y me voy a C:\xampp\htdocs\periodico, y escribo "git push heroku master":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y me sale este mensaje de error, impidiendome que pase el proyecto a Heroku.
Parece que el fallo esta en composer.json, por lo que dejo el código:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "caouecs/laravel-lang": "^3.0",
        "codedge/laravel-fpdf": "^1.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master",
        "thujohn/pdf": "^1.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "^4.1",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Edito: Voy a mostrar información dada por la propia página de Heroku:
Para ello, primero me voy aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto me lleva a esta información:

```
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.

            Detected buildpacks: PHP,Node.js

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order

-----> PHP app detected

-----> Bootstrapping...

-----> Installing platform packages...

       - php (7.3.5)

       - ext-gd (bundled with php)

       - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)

       - apache (2.4.39)

       - nginx (1.14.2)

-----> Installing dependencies...

       Composer version 1.8.5 2019-04-09 17:46:47

       Loading composer repositories with package information

       Installing dependencies from lock file

       Package operations: 59 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

         - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.5.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/css-selector (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/routing (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/debug (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/finder (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/console (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.6): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.1.3): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing ramsey/uuid (3.8.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing symfony/translation (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.25.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing monolog/monolog (1.24.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.48): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing erusev/parsedown (1.7.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.2.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing laravel/framework (v5.6.39): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.1.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.8.3): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing caouecs/laravel-lang (3.0.58): Downloading (100%)         

         - Installing codedge/laravel-fpdf (1.2.3): Downloading (100%)         

         - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.0.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing illuminate/html (v5.0.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing intervention/image (dev-master e82d274): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (v0.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.1.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing psy/psysh (v0.9.9): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.8): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing pclzip/pclzip (2.8.2): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing phpmailer/phpmailer (v6.0.6): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.6.0): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing phpoffice/common (0.2.9): Downloading (100%)

         - Installing phpoffice/phpword (dev-master 9d65414): Downloading (100%)         

         - Installing thujohn/pdf (1.0.6): Downloading (100%)         

         - Installing twbs/bootstrap (v4.1.3): Downloading (100%)         

         - Installing yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle (v8.11.0): Downloading (100%)         

       Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelcollective/html instead.

       Generating optimized autoload files





         [RuntimeException]                                                                                      

         Could not scan for classes inside "database/factories" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder  





       install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...



 !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!

 !     

 !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause

 !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or

 !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')

 !     in your 'composer.json'.

 !     

 !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,

 !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.

 !     

 !     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of

 !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning

 !     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.

 !     

 !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to

 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.

 !     Push failed
```